# Python to Postgres insert Geometry syntax

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, sql, psycopg2

Having trouble creating geom columns and inserting geometry lat lng values into postgres table

1. Is my syntax correct in creating the point geometry fields? st_makepoint is the point constructor. when I create the column should I be using that?
2. or should I be using the st_makepoint when inserting into the column?

*python 2.7

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("connected")
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE example(pgeom geometry(POINT, 4326),
         dgeom geometry(POINT, 4326));''')
for x in csvfile:
    extracting info...
    1geom = lng1+lat1 #int values
    2geom = lng2+lng2 #int values
    query = '''insert into example(geom1, geom2) values (%s,%s);'''
    data = (1geom, 2geom)
    cur.execute(query, data)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I think you should expand your code snippet to show where you set `cur`.

Comment: st_makepoint is the point constructor I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read your CSV file and create a `vars_list` list of tuples to insert. Reading the CSV file is off topic, but it should have a structure something like this:

```
vars_list = [
    (lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2),  # first record
    (lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2),  # second
    ...
]
```

Then insert them all at once with `executemany`, like this:

```
sql = '''\
INSERT INTO example(pickup_geom, dropoff_geom)
VALUES(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(%s, %s), 4326));
'''
curs.executemany(sql, vars_list)
conn.commit()
```

Or if you want to individually insert records:

```
for vars in vars_list:
    curs.execute(sql, vars)
    conn.commit()
```

Comment: I have thousands of records, should I still use the executemany function?

Comment: I'd guess executemany is faster, although you could do a test to see.